# Using moderncv with multibib on TexMaker IDE, can't get an automatic compilation of document

Tags: texmaker, moderncv, multibib

I am trying to using multibib with moderncv documentclass and it works fine, but I have to perform several manual steps that I would rather be able to have TexMaker automate. I just can't figure out how to do that.

My `.tex` file is pretty large so I will hopefully but just the necessary parts down.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 


\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{purple} 

\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}


\newcites{pubs,post}{{Publications},{Posters}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyhead}[1]{}


\section{Publications}
\nocitepubs{*}
\bibliographystylepubs{plain}
\bibliographypubs{publications}


\section{Conferences}
\subsection{Posters}
\nocitepost{*}
\bibliographystylepost{plain}
\bibliographypost{posters}

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Right now I compile my tex file using the following quick build

```
PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX (x2) + View Pdf
```

Then I have to execute the following in the terminal

```
bibtex pubs.aux
bibtex post.aux
```

Then I go back and re-compile with quick build and it gives me the following message back:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary
file: BrianCV.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file BrianCV.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file BrianCV.aux I found no 
bibstyle command---while reading file BrianCV.aux (There were 3 error messages)
```

However, if I click `View Pdf` it comes up perfectly compiled. So technically there is not issues and I am able to get the results I want but I would rather all those steps I have to take be done in the quick build. Also I would prefer if the message that pops up didn't prevent my pdf from being viewed by quick build.

Can someone help me with that?